# Remove duplicate from a file or table

Tags: python, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, anaconda

I have data in a database table and I'm exporting this to a file like this and there are around 100k records (this is kind of duplicate based on id)

```
            id     |  dp_1   | pp_1  | Phone  |
            -------|---------|-------|--------|
            1      | dp1     |       | phone1 |
            ----------------------------------|
            1      |         | pp1   | phone1 |
            ----------------------------------|
            2      |  dp2    | pp2   | phone2 |
            ------------------------------------
            2      |         |       | phone4 |
            -----------------------------------
            3      |  dp3    | pp3   | phone3 |
            ------------------------------------
            3      |  dp3    |       | phone3 |
            -----------------------------------
            4      |         | pp4   |        |
            ------------------------------------
            4      |  dp4    |       |        |
```

I wanted the result to be as below:

```
            id     |  dp_1   | pp_1  | Phone           |
            -------|---------|-------|-----------------|
            1      | dp1     |  pp1  | phone1 - phone1 |
            -------------------------------------------|
            2      | dp2     | pp2   | phone2 - phone4 |
            -------------------------------------------|
            3      | dp3     | pp3   | phone3          |
            -------------------------------------------|

            4      |   dp4   | pp4   |                 |
            --------------------------------------------
```

I have written this SQL:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT*, 
 row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY id,DP_1, PP_1, phone ORDER BY id desc) 
 AS [rn]
 FROM table1
   )
Select * into #temp from cte WHERE [rn] = 1 ORDER BY id
```

How can I achieve this in Python OR using SQL query? I'm using Anaconda.

Comment: Why does id 3 only have `phone3`, but id 1 has `phone1 - phone1`? Why is the logic different for these 2?

Comment: Refereed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string Need to still modify few more things.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand why id 1 and 3 have different logic for phone (one duplicates the number, one does not). This answer can either duplicate the phone (like in id 1) or return the `DISTINCT` values (like id 3). You can change the logic by uncommenting the `GROUP BY`.

```
--Sample Data
WITH VTE AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES (1,'dp1',NULL,'phone1'),
                 (1,NULL,'pp1','phone1'),
                 (2,'dp2','pp2','phone2'),
                 (2,NULL,NULL,'phone4'),
                 (3,'dp3','pp2','phone3'),
                 (3,'dp3',NULL,'phone3')) V(id, dp_1, pp_1, phone))
--And the answer
SELECT id,
       MAX(dp_1) AS dp_1,
       MAX(pp_1) AS pp_1,
       STUFF((SELECT ' - ' + sq.phone 
              FROM VTE sq
              WHERE sq.id = VTE.id
                AND phone <> ''
              --GROUP BY sq.phone --If you only want to display unique phones, uncomment the GROUP BY.
              FOR XML PATH('')),1,3,'') AS [phone]
FROM VTE
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: Looking like problem is here  when phone number is blank. Just modified the question for blank phone number scenario. I have so may columns like this (just collected few as an example)

Comment: @AskMe blank or NULL? Also, what is the "problem"?

Comment: @Askme I have modified the query for if the value of `phone` is blank (this is **not** the same as *`NULL`*; as you specified blank I have only catered for that. Should you require logic for *`NULL`* I suggest you add a `IS NOT NULL` and (probably) an `ISNULL` around the entire subquery ). No further logic changes in regards to ID 1 and 3, as I am yet to have a response on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This Query gives your expected Result

```
;With cte( id,dp_1,pp_1,Phone)
AS
(            
 SELECT 1 ,  'dp1' , NULL   , 'phone1'   UNION ALL
 SELECT 1 ,   NULL , 'pp1'  , 'phone1'   UNION ALL
 SELECT 2 ,  'dp2' , 'pp2'  , 'phone2'   UNION ALL
 SELECT 2 ,   NULL ,  NULL  , 'phone4'   UNION ALL
 SELECT 3 ,  'dp3' , 'pp3'  , 'phone3'   UNION ALL
 SELECT 3 ,  'dp3' ,  NULL  , 'phone3'   
 )
 SELECT 
     DISTINCT id  , 
     MAX(dp_1)OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) AS dp_1 ,
     MAX(pp_1)OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) AS pp_1,
 STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT  ' - ' + Phone  FROM cte i WHERE i.id=o.id
FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2,'') AS Phone
FROM cte o
```

Result

```
id  dp_1     pp_1    Phone
--------------------------------
1   dp1      pp1     phone1 
2   dp2      pp2     phone2 - phone4
3   dp3      pp3     phone3
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python the best solution in your case is [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/). I also use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) to select unique variables for the "phones" in your case

First, I just create your table (reading from SQL is a separate question I guess)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'id': [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3],
                        'dp_1': ['dp1', np.nan, 'dp2', np.nan, 'dp3', 'dp3'],
                        'pp_1': [np.nan, 'pp1', 'pp2', np.nan, 'pp3', np.nan],
                        'Phone': ['phone1 ', 'phone1 ', 'phone2 ', 'phone4 ', 'phone2 ', 'phone3 ']})
```

Then I create a function which will be applied in grouping

```
def unique_sum(str_list):
    return np.sum(np.unique(str_list))
```

and then apply groupby. I hope that's what you need

```
df.groupby('id').aggregate({'dp_1': 'last', 'pp_1': 'last', 'Phone': unique_sum})


    pp_1           Phone dp_1
id                          
1   pp1         phone1   dp1
2   pp2  phone2 phone4   dp2
3   pp3  phone2 phone3   dp3
```